# Display a relationship collection ordered by the latest in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Please I need to display comments by relationship ordered by the latest.

Here is my code:

```php
$comments = Post::Find($post->id)->comment()->paginate(5);
              
return view('posts.post-page',[
    'comments' => $comments,
    'post' => $post
]);
```

Comment: Why do you query the post and query it again with its id to get its comments?

Comment: So, what is your problem ? You just have to do `->comment()->latest()->paginate(5);`.

Comment: ``$comments = $post->comments()->latest()->paginate(5);``

Answer (score 0):

add `->latest()` before `->paginate(5)`